I can't get Python autocomplete to work with NvChad + python-lsp-server
I'm trying to use Neovim with Python, and I can't get autocomplete to work. I have created a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:
For this example, I'll run everything in a fresh Alpine container for environment isolation:
docker run -w /root -it --rm alpine:latest sh
apk add git nodejs neovim ripgrep build-base curl python3 --update

Create an example project with numpy in it.
python -m venv /root/myvenv
. /root/myvenv/bin/activate
pip install numpy

Use NvChad and enable python-lsp-server and the python treesitter plugin:
git clone https://github.com/NvChad/starter ~/.config/nvim
cat <<EOF > ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/init.lua
return {
  {
    "stevearc/conform.nvim",
    -- event = 'BufWritePre', -- uncomment for format on save
    config = function()
      require "configs.conform"
    end,
  },

  -- These are some examples, uncomment them if you want to see them work!
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    config = function()
      require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").defaults()
      require "configs.lspconfig"
    end,
  },

  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "lua-language-server", "stylua",
        "html-lsp", "css-lsp" , "prettier",
        "python-lsp-server"
      },
    },
  },

  {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "vim", "lua", "vimdoc",
            "html", "css",
            "python"
      },
    },
  },
}
EOF

Open a new file:
nvim example.py

On the first start, nvim will load the required plugins. (I verified that they do load.) Once nvim is ready, type this in the file:
import numpy

numpy.linalg.matrix_power

This should autocomplete the matrix_power() function, but it doesn't suggest or complete this. Why not?
Edit:
Autocompletion happens automatically, but this is what it shows: (No numpy methods at all.)


Are you pressing any completion keys? It looks like you are asking why typing the name of a function doesn't automatically complete the function; see :help ins-completion. Usually one presses C-x and another key to trigger completion. (Thanks for the minimal example, btw.)

With the variety of vim configurations, that's something to consider, but with NvChad, autocompletion happens automatically. I updated my question to include a screenshot of what I see.

I figured it out.
From the list of LSP servers, I found I needed to install python-lsp-server like so:
apk add py3-lsp-server

Then I needed to edit ~/.config/nvim/lua/configs/lspconfig.lua to add pylsp to servers like so:
local servers = { "html", "cssls", "pylsp" }

